# How Display Month which is Start with Current Month Using PHP?

Tags: php, date, leap-year

I want to display all month with current year but it must be start with current month like below.

I need like if current month `October` and year `2019` then option list should be start with `2019-10` then all renaming month with current year like below.

**Output**

```
<select>
            <option value="">SELECT MONTH</option>
            <option value="2019-10">October-2019</option>     
            <option value="2019-11">November-2019</option>     
            <option value="2019-12">December-2019</option>     
            <option value="2019-01">January-2019</option>     
            <option value="2019-02">February-2019</option>     
            <option value="2019-03">March-2019</option>     
            <option value="2019-04">April-2019</option>     
            <option value="2019-05">May-2019</option>     
            <option value="2019-06">June-2019</option>     
            <option value="2019-07">July-2019</option>     
            <option value="2019-08">August-2019</option>     
            <option value="2019-09">September-2019</option>     
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Working and give me exact output as i want.

```
<select>
    <option value="">SELECT MONTH</option>
    <?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) 
    {
        $getMonth = strtotime(sprintf('%d months', $i));   
        $monthLabel = date('F', $getMonth)."-".date("Y");
        $monthval = date("Y")."-".date('m', $getMonth); ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $monthval; ?>"><?php echo $monthLabel; ?></option>
    <?php } 
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this PHP code you can get current_month

```
date_default_timezone_get();
$month= date('Y-m', time());
```

Then you simply need to fill your 'select' tag with options in the correct order

Answer (score 0):

Use the DateTime class. Create an array as follows:

```
$dt = date_create('first Day of this Month 00:00');  //start
$valueCaption = [];
$numberOptions = 5;
for($i=0;$i<$numberOptions;$i++){
  $valueCaption[$dt->format('Y-m')] = $dt->format('F-Y');
  $dt->modify('+1 Month');
}
```

returns a array $valueCaption how

```
array (
  '2019-10' => "October-2019",
  '2019-11' => "November-2019",
  '2019-12' => "December-2019",
  '2020-01' => "January-2020",
  '2020-02' => "February-2020",
)
```

You use this array when outputting with a foreach ($valueCaption as $value => $caption) to create your options.